# How to pass three parameters to url address using ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

For now I have a procedure I wish to call:

```
CALL Get_Discharge_Station('2022-02-02', 6, 11800);
```

I want to pass these three parameters - `2022-02-02,6,11800` to url address, when I enter different date,number and number of station to get different data.

For now my API controller look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/hqdataahs")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HQ_data_AHSController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public HQ_data_AHSController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            string query = @"CALL Get_Discharge_Station('2022-02-02', 6, 11800);";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AppCon");

            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                mycon.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader);

                    myReader.Close();
                    mycon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult(table);
        }
    }
}
```

What can I change to pass there three parameters in url address when I access the controller?`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use parameterized queries to be secure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just fix the action

```
 [HttpGet("~/api/hqdataahs/GetData")]
  //or just
 [HttpGet("GetData")]
 public JsonResult Get(string date, int num, int statNum)
{
    string query = $"CALL Get_Discharge_Station('{date}', {num}, {statNum});";
    .....
```

and carefully read all comments below about sql injection.

you url should be

```
https://.../api/hqdataahs/GetData?date=2022-02-02&num=6&statNum=11800
```

or change route

```
 [HttpGet("~/api/hqdataahs/GetData/{date}/{num}/{statNum}")]
  //or just
 [HttpGet("GetData/{date}/{num}/{statNum}")]
[HttpGet("~api/hqdataahs/GetData
 public JsonResult Get(string date, int num, int statNum)
```

in this case you url should be

```
https://.../api/hqdataahs/GetData/2022-02-02/6/11800
```

Comment: I try with your method but my route is [Route("api/hqdataahs")], how to access the API page ?

Comment: @BenJohnson Just don forget  that route should start with "~/"    [Route("~/.. and you can select  for the route any words that you like, it should be the same for url

Comment: How to be api/hqdataahs/GetData?date=2022-02-02&num=6&staNum=11800 ?

Comment: Can you change your answer like that, please

Answer (score 1):

declare the args

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get(string dataStr, int noodle, int frumpy)
    {
```

now construct the call

```
  string query = $"CALL Get_Discharge_Station('{dateStr}', {noodle}, {fumpy});"
```

Comment: How to call after that ?

Comment: @BenJohnson see serge answer

Comment: Ok but my route is different